# Contentful.php SDK missing

Tags: php, api, sdk, contentful

When requesting:

```
php composer.phar install contentful/contentful
```

as stated in the tutorial, the `require` function is suggested by Composer.
However, when requesting:

```
php composer.phar require contentful/contentful
```

this is the feedback that is received:

```
 Problem 1
- The requested package contentful/contentful could not be found in any version, there may be a typo in the package name.
```

How do you install the SDK in this case? 
Is this the only way to implement Contentful with PHP?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Contentful developer here.

The `contentful/contentful` package is currently only available as beta. To install a beta quality package just append `:@beta` to the command. The full command will look like this:

```
php composer.phar require contentful/contentful:@beta
```

While you could manually copy the SDK into your project, I'd advice strongly against it as you'll have to keep it up to date manually.